# Usage of "focal" in a sentence

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

If I am referring to a group of n cells, labeled by c(1), ..., c(n), and I want to refer to a typical cell c(i), for a general i, is it correct to use the word "focal" as follows

"For a **focal** cell c(i), c(i+1) and c(i-1) are its neighbours"?

Comment: For a *typical* cell c(i) ... Labelling it `i` means it *isn't* specific. A specific cell would be say c(42).

Comment: Thanks, corrected.

Comment: You can leave out the word *focal* and the sentence makes [better?] sense. Why do you want to use a word like *focal* here? What has your research already shown about the word *focal*?

Comment: '... arbitrary'.

Comment: @AndrewLeach it is often used in mathematics. For example, when referring to focal individuals in a certain model. I just wanted to know more about its usage, but I understand your viewpoint.

Comment: So you're asking from a domain-specific standpoint (or for a domain-specific answer)? That is, rather than *just* English, you are asking about English *specific to mathematics*?

Comment: _Focal_ in any context refers to _focus_, which in turn refers to visual acuity, which is only possible for humans when concentrating on a small portion of the visual field. Metaphorically then, _focal_ in the context of a group of _n_ cells (whatever _cell_ means here) means some central subgroup or neighborhood (in the mathematical sense) of cells that are being discussed in the text. The English word _only_ is a word that is said to have a _focus_, which is some constituent that _only_ binds, wherever it appears. _He only saw Karen_ has _Karen_ as focus; _Only he saw her_ has _he_ as focus.

Comment: Contrary to a focused cell, c(i) is everyman. You are talking about a *random* or *sample* value to serve as an example of any cell. @EdwinAshworth has arbitrary, which c(i) is.

Comment: I see that *focal cell* is a term in biology and image processing, but I haven't been able to find technical definitions.  Therefore I don't know the answer to your question.  However, in the math and computational worlds, random, sample, and arbitrary are all good terms.  But it is traditional that in an array in a computer program, or even just an algorithm, the neighbors of *c(i)* on either side, respectively, will be *c(i-1)* and *c(i+1)*.  So I would say that typically, the sentence you asked us to check would be omitted as being obvious.  However, your audience might ...

Comment: ... not be used to this notation.  In that case, I guess it would be good to set things up rigorously.  I think your best bet is to look in your target journal to see how other authors talk about this kind of model.

Comment: I suggest this isn't about English, but Maths or some other specific, technical language. That might be considered a subset of English but how do specialised subsets qualify for consideration in SE ELU?

Answer (score 3):

The word **given** is likely a more idiomatic choice:

> For a **given** cell c(i), c(i+1) and c(i-1) are its neighbours.

[OxfordLD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/given_1) defines it as "that you have stated and are discussing; particular."